# Dynamic variable in Jenkins pipeline with groovy method variable

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile in Groovy for a declarative pipeline and two created Jenkins variables with names OCP_TOKEN_VALUE_ONE and OCP_TOKEN_VALUE_TWO and the corresponding values. The problem comes when I try to pass a method variable and use it in an sh command.

I have the next code:

```
private def deployToOpenShift(projectProps, environment, openshiftNamespaceGroupToken) {  
  sh """/opt/ose/oc login ${OCP_URL} --token=${openshiftNamespaceGroupToken} --namespace=${projectProps.namespace}-${environment}"""
}
```

The problem is, the method `deployToOpenShift` has in the `openshiftNamespaceGroupToken` variable, a value that is the name of variable that has been set in Jenkins. It needs to be dynamic and the problem is that Jenkins don't resolve the Jenkins variable value, just the one passed as String, I mean, the result is:

> --token=OCP_TOKEN_VALUE_ONE

If I put in the code

```
private def deployToOpenShift(projectProps, environment, openshiftNamespaceGroupToken) {  
  sh """/opt/ose/oc login ${OCP_URL} --token=${OCP_TOKEN_VALUE_ONE} --namespace=${projectProps.namespace}-${environment}"""
}
```

works perfect but is not dynamic that is the point of the method variable. I have tried with the """ stuff as you can see, but not working.

Any extra idea?

**Edited** with the code that calls the method:

```
...
projectProps = readProperties file: './gradle.properties'
openShiftTokenByGroup = 'OCP_TOKEN_' + projectProps.namespace.toUpperCase()

...

stage ('Deploy-Dev') {
  agent any
  steps {
    milestone ordinal : 10, label: "Deploy-Dev Milestone"
    deployToOpenShift(projectProps, 'dev', openShiftTokenByGroup)
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the method?

Comment: Edited with the code @RobHales

Comment: Your code is wrong because it define a simple string OCP_TOKEN_VALUE_ONE which is the name of the variable but not the value of it!

Comment: @yorammi but as I told, this string is the name of a Jenkins variable which is correctly evaluated in the openshift plugin in another stage:
openshiftBuild apiURL: "${OCP_URL}", authToken: "${openShiftTokenByGroup}", namespace: "${projectProps.namespace}-dev"
I think the problem comes with the sh command stuff

Comment: OK. Did you try to put ' instead of """ to wrap the sh command? For my experience it behave differently in some cases.

Comment: Yeah, not working with this change. Anyway I have a solution for this using evaluate in Groovy. With this line of code I can do what I want. I don't know if I should add this as my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have got two different ways to do that. One is using `evaluate` from groovy like this:

```
def openShiftTokenByGroup = 'OCP_TOKEN_' + projectProps.namespace.toUpperCase()

evaluate("${openShiftTokenByGroup}") //This will resolve the configured value in Jenkins
```

The second one is the same approach but in the sh command with `eval` escaping the $ character:

```
sh """ 
eval \$$openShiftTokenByGroup
echo "Token: $openShiftTokenByGroup
 """
```

This will do the magic too and you'll get the Jenkins configured value.

Comment: Can it evaluate from a var that reads from json?
config = readJSON(file: 'config.json')
config.RHEL6_SOURCE_IMAGE_FAMILY

Comment: Hi @dcalap...Can you please help me out with my query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63467568/substitute-values-from-property-file-in-jenkinsfile-for-dynamically-set-variable

Comment: @dcalap I've tried your solution, but it didn't work because it's looking for the variables value that is mentioned through another variable, on a new section of the pipelin called script 1