# Substitute values from property file in Jenkinsfile for dynamically set variables

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile with multiple parameters that are environment-specific.

The values for those parameters are stored in a property file. I am trying to set the variables based upon the selected environment and then replace their values from the property files.

**Jenkinsfile**

ENVIRONMENT is a choice parameter having 2 values: ft, perf and pm as below in my Jenkinsfile

```
choice (
        name: 'ENVIRONMENT',
        choices: ['ft', 'perf','pm'],
        description: 'please select the environment'
        )
```

PROPERTY_FILE is another choice parameter as below

```
 choice (
        name: 'PROPERTY_FILE',
        choices: ['jenkins/app.groovy'],
        description: 'please select the property file'
        )
```

app.groovy looks like:

```
Test_perf="Hello"
Test_ft="World"
Test_pm="Welcome"
```

**Stages**

```
stage('Load Environment Property File') {
                    steps {
                        script {
                                //sourcing user selected property file
                                load "${PROPERTY_FILE}"
                                def envName = "${PROPERTY_FILE}".tokenize(".")[0]
                                //it will set build description as description in Jenkins build history
                                env.envName=envName
                                currentBuild.description = "Env:${envName}"
                                }
                          }
                }
```

//STAGE FOR WHICH I NEED HELP

```
stage('Set Variables Based upon environment name') {
                    steps {
                           script{
                                if ("${ENVIRONMENT}" ==  "perf" ){
                                    var="\${Test_"+"${DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT}"+"}"
                                    echo "${var}" //output is ${Test_pm} and is correct as the substitution happens.
                                    //NOW, I AM TRYING TO echo "HELLO", i.e.; replacing the variable "${Test_perf}" stuffed inside "var" from the property file. However, since the property file is already loaded, it will not replace the key by its value from the property file.
                                } else if ("${ENVIRONMENT}" ==  "ft" ){
                                    var="\${Test_"+"${DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT}"+"}"
                                    echo "${var}" //output is ${Test_ft} and is correct as the substitution happens.
                                    //NOW, I AM TRYING TO echo "World" 
                                } else {
                                    var="\${Test_"+"${DEPLOYMENT_ENVIRONMENT}"+"}"
                                    echo "${var}" //output is ${Test_pm} and is correct as the substitution happens.
                                    //NOW, I AM TRYING TO echo "Welcome"
                                } 
                            }

                    }
                }
```

Is there a way to further substitute the value from the property file. For e.g.; "${var}" expands to "${Test_pm}" and then "${Test_pm}" gets the value "Welcome" from the property file.
Please help.

Comment: Have you tried my solution using evaluate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326582/1230748

Comment: Yes, I tried. But it is also not able to replace the dynamic variable by its value.

Comment: Maybe if I understand what and why you want to do that I can help you. I don't see the point of wrapp another variable inside the file since you just can directly call a function that returns a String from the loaded file because you are already putting in place an if's block to filter between environments